# How to find all the days & hours, between two columns say .. Datetime1 & Datetime2 . How to do it in Python or Excel

Tags: python, excel

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqlKC.png) is the problem of which I want to list out each hour in between.

```
Issue Reported                               Issue Resolved

01-12-19 05:00:00                           02-12-19  07:00:00

07-12-19 08:00:00                          07-12-19  11:00:00
```

I expect results to be :

```
[                      
01-12-19 06:00:00,                            
01-12-19 07:00:00,                         
01-12-19 08:00:00,                      
01-12-19 09:00:00,                                   
---                                               
02-12-19 05:00:00,                                    
02-12-19 06:00:00                                       
                ]                                                 
 [                       
 07-12-19 09:00:00                                                      
 07-12-19 10:00:00
                                       ]
```

Comment: This isn't exactly clear. Can you provide more detail? What are the inputs? What are the outputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a list of hours between two dates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683774/have-a-list-of-hours-between-two-dates-in-python)

Comment: you should post your attempt to solve the problem - or at least an exact description of the problem. Also sharing the table data to test further solutions would be nice!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349258/python-printing-all-hours-between-two-datetime-accounting-for-daylight-saving/37356117

Answer (score 0):

result_total = []
for i in range(0,1241):
        z = pd.to_datetime(df.Issue_Reported[i])
        result_total.append( z +  pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(df.FAULTY_HOURS[i]), 'H'))
        print(result_total)

### HERE **FAULTY_HOURS** is the no. hours between ISSUE REPORTED & ISSUE RESOLVED